# Enzyme `mount` not rendering `Route` elements

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have this simplified `render()` method:

```jsx
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route path='/abc' component={Test} />
                    <Route path='/def' render={() => (
                        <div>Hello</div>
                    )} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

And this enzyme test:

```jsx
test('Render <Test> on /abc', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/abc']} >
            <App />
        </MemoryRouter>
    );
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.find(Test)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
});
```

However, `mount()`is not rendering either component `Test` on `/abc` route, or `<div>Hello</div>` on `/def` route.

Output from `console.log(wrapper.debug());`:

```html
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={{...}}>
    <Router history={{...}}>
      <App>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Router history={{...}}>
            <div>
              <Route path="/abc" component={[Function: Test]} />
              <Route path="/def" render={[Function: render]} />
            </div>
          </Router>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </App>
    </Router>
  </MemoryRouter>
```

How do I test that app will actually render `Test` component on `/abc` route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution my mocking the router:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
const reactRouterDom = require('react-router-dom');

// Render plain div with children
reactRouterDom.BrowserRouter = ({children}) => <div>{children}</div>
module.exports = reactRouterDom;
```